# jsPlumb connect sources and targets programmatically

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I am building an UI with jsPlumb were I have multiple boxes that can be connected together. Each box has 1 target and 3 sources, made with the `makeTarget` and `makeSource` methods called upon the same box DOM element.

```
jsPlumb.makeTarget($('#box_id'), targetData);
jsPlumb.makeSource($('#box_id'), sourceData1);
jsPlumb.makeSource($('#box_id'), sourceData2);
jsPlumb.makeSource($('#box_id'), sourceData3);
```

And each of the sources is distinguished by the filter property that connects it to a different part of the box:

```
sourceData1.filter = '.filter_1';
sourceData2.filter = '.filter_2';
sourceData3.filter = '.filter_3';
```

Connections are possible to be made only between the sources of one box and the target of another box. The target anchors are `Continuous`.

This arrangement works perfectly for what I need as far as working with the boxes and dragging and dropping connections.

The problem arises when I want to recreate a saved UI from a JSON object. I can recreate the position of the boxes without a problem, but I cannot find a way to recreate the connections to start from the correct source of the 3 available on the box.

I tried to re-connect using the saved uuids, but it turned out the endpoints don't exist yet before the connections are created.
The other method I tried is to connect just the source and target box ids:

```
jsPlumb.connect({ 
    source:"box_id1", 
    target:"box_id2",
});
```

But this never connects the correct source to the target and the connections are not exactly the same as the user made them. If a connection started from source 1, with this method it can start from source 3 for example.

Basically I am asking is it possible to programmatically connect sources and targets before the endpoints are created using the jsPlumb API?

So is it possible to recreate the connections in these circumstances or should I look for other solutions?

Thanks.

**Note:**
You can find more info about the UI, its setting and the problem here: https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb/issues/77

Comment: have you tried specifying the anchors and endpoints via a 'common' var as described in http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/connections#common

Comment: I have been trying to do it like this, but from some reason it creates incorrect connections all the time. The problem is I have not found way in jsPlumb to connect sources and targets programmatically before the endpoints are created.

Answer (score 0):

try assigning uuids to your endpoints.

```
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint('#box_id', { uuid: $('#box_id_source1' }, {isSource: true,isTarget: false});
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint('#box_id', { uuid: $('#box_id_source2' }, {isSource: true,isTarget: false});
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint('#box_id', { uuid: $('#box_id_source3' }, {isSource: true,isTarget: false});
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint('#box_id', { uuid: $('#box_id_target1' }, {isSource: false,isTarget: true});
```

now that You have assigned uuids to you endpoints. it will be easy to make connections between them after laoding from JSON:

```
jsPlumb.connect({uuids: ['#box_id_source1', '#box_id_target1']});
```

hope this helps or gives you an idea